# save custom values to preference in android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preference settings for which i have configured a dialog box pop up on click of preference using the below code.

```
Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(this);
passwordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.password_dialog);
passwordDialog.setTitle("Set new password.");
passwordDialog.setCancelable(true);
passwordDialog.show();
```

The dialog is coming fine. However In the dialog i have a password edit text and a confirm password edit text. If these matches with each other i need to save the password to preference. I do not know how to save the value to a preference on ok click in my custom dialog. Please let me know how to do this. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the preferences, and then commit information to it :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
preferences.edit().putString("passwordKey", editText.getText().toString()).commit();
```

To add information to a preference, start by calling edit() (returns an editor), add the value you want (key/value, like a Map), and never forget to call commit() (to commit the changes).

You can then access your value using

```
preferences.getString("passwordKey", defaultValue);
```